# Is there an equivalent to the Java EE ServletContext in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, servlets, jakarta-ee

I need a way to store application-level data (i.e. cross user sessions) in ASP.NET. In Java EE I'd use the ServletContext. Is there an equivalent in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what you say (cross-user sessions) the closest you get to that in ASP.NET is through [HttpApplicationState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.application.aspx) object.